# Mavenising an Eclipse Java project without the wizard

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

This is probably a basic question for you here but here goes:

I'm building a java project using Maven in eclipse at the moment. I have a pom.xml file which is working fine, but I need to be able to organise my source files into 'src/main/java' and resources into 'src/main/resources' etc. Any other maven projects I've looked at are structured like this and the build goes to success without picking up any source files, since it "skips non existent resourceDirectory src/main/resources" and the others.

I currently have a source folder 'src', and eclipse won't let me add more source folders with 'src' in the name.

Any guidance whatsoever would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try right-clicking on the project and selecting `Maven->Update Project Configuration` from the context menu. Then refresh the project. If your pom is close to right, that should represent your project in eclipse the way you want.

Comment: Thanks, that seems to be doing it. The project layout is almost what I want, should only take a bit more fiddling with the pom.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just open your pom.xml file in eclipse? It can recognize it and will built its project files correspondingly

Comment: So my pom file should define the structure of these folders within the project? I have added the xml in the pom to define the names of the folders for my source, resources, tests etc. but it doesn't build them when I run the maven build.

Answer (score 1):

In eclipse `right click over the project / Build Path / Configure Build Path / Source (tab)/ Add folder` and select the source folder you want. If the folder you need doesn't exist under */src/main* create it following the maven conventions.

after that I would recommend:

```
mvn eclipse:clean eclipse:eclipse
```

Comment: Yes I stumbled across that just there. Thanks for all the help. Much appreciated.